# Arrow images not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just starting out with HTML and CSS and using an HTML 5 purchased template to put together my site. There is a slider for quotes with back and forward arrows (click or scroll to the About section) and the arrows are not showing up. I am sure it's something silly I have done, but I cannot figure it out. Here's the in progress site:  http://radability.co/index.html

Any help would really be appreciated!

Thank you, Hillary

Comment: your arrows are white and therefore you can't see them on a white background. but before that you should get rid of that css which removes your background image and sets the background to white. first thing you should learn is how to use developer tools which come with most browsers.

Comment: A quick look at your HTML reveals that large portions are commented out, some incorrectly, which means the browsers won't respond consistently to what you're doing. Fix the broken HTML and try again.

Comment: Mike, my dev friend agreed - I had incorrectly commented-out a section which corrupted several things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your element you'll see in your favorite developer tool that the related element's styles look like:

```
#quotes_slider_container > .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:before {
    content: "";
}
```

*note the unsupported character.*

by fixing/changing that rule with this characters: ￩  ￫ this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use developer tool, you will find this code

```
#quotes_slider_container > .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev, #quotes_slider_container > .flex-direction-nav .flex-next{
background: none #fff;
}
```

overwrite the background-image

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev{
background: url(../images/bg-prev.png) center no-repeat;
.
.
}
```

resolve this issue and it will see the arrows again.

Comment: @HillaryRadbill you may want to select it as "correct answer" if it fixed your problem.